# When find command errors can I append the data in look up list to prevent future errors

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet of data which I am trying to "clean" using VBA.

I am going through each column and replacing data that I have seen before with known abbreviated values. However when I come across a new value that I do not have an abbreviation for I need to attribute this to a known abbreviation. I then need to add this known link to the look up data so if I come across this value again I have an abbreviation to replace it with.

In below example, my code loops down `Column A` and replaces each value with the lookup abbreviation in `Column C`. The known link in `Column B` allows this look up to work.

When the loop gets to `row 6` it cannot look up so errors. At this point I want to pop up a distinct list of the abbreviations in `Column C` to select from and then add this link to the bottom on `Column B` & `C` so that when the loop reaches line 13 it knows this link and can look up without an error.
(Msg Box just a marker, can be removed)

(Apologies if the terminology in not correct - new to VBA)

```
Column A              Column B           Column C
---------             ---------          --------- 
Dry clean             Dry clean          DCLN
Wipe clean            Machine wash       MWSH
Machine wash          Wipe clean         WPCL
40C Machine Wash      40C Machine Wash   MWSH
Wipe clean            30C Machine Wash   MWSH
Machinewash
Dry clean
Wipe clean 
Machine Wash
Wipe clean
40C Machine Wash
30C Machine Wash
Machinewash
```

My VBA code is as below;

```
Sub replace_wash()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim myLastReplaceRow As Long  
Dim myLastDataRow As Long  
Dim myRow As Long  
Dim myFind As String  
Dim myReplace As String  

myLastReplaceRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row  
myLastDataRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  

For myRow = 1 To myLastDataRow  

myFind = Cells(myRow, "A")  
myReplace = Application.IfError(ApplicationVlookup(myFind, Columns("B:C"), 2, False), "ERROR")  

Application.DisplayAlerts = True  

If myReplace = "ERROR" Then  
MsgBox "invalid value"  
Else  

Cells(myRow, "A").Replace What:=myFind, Replacement:=myReplace, LookAt:=xlWhole, _  
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _  
ReplaceFormat:=False  

End If  

Next myRow  
Exit Sub  

End Sub
```

The output I want is:

```
Column A              Column B           Column C
---------             ---------          --------- 
DCLN                  Dry clean          DCLN
WPCL                  Machine wash       MWSH
MWSH                  Wipe clean         WPCL
MWSH                  40C Machine Wash   MWSH
WPCL                  30C Machine Wash   MWSH
MWSH                  Machinewash        MWSH
DCLN                  
WPCL                  
MWSH                  
WPCL                  
MWSH                  
MWSH                  
MWSH
```

Comment: Hey, your post has a lot of form and spelling / grammar mistakes. Please format your code according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) guide.

Comment: Solved using a combo box within a user form